# Compare on mysql table column with a cell on another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table I want to get the data from and this depends on another cell on another table.

main:

```
 .. | d1 | d2 | d3 | time1 
----+----+----+----+-----
 .. | 1  | 12 | .. | 2019-02-20 21:20:55
 .. | 3  | 2  | .. | 2019-02-20 21:24:00
 .. | 1  | 5  | .. | 2019-02-21 15:57:14
 .. | 15 | 12 | .. | 2019-02-21 16:15:12
```

secondary:

```
 .. | .. | .. | .. | time2
----+----+----+----+-----
 .. | .. | .. | .. | 2019-02-20 20:39:55
 .. | .. | .. | .. | 2019-02-20 21:14:00
 .. | .. | .. | .. | 2019-02-21 13:56:14
 .. | .. | .. | .. | 2019-02-21 15:52:22
```

**I want to be able to get the sum of d1 and d2 for every row where time1 is bigger than the last cell on time2**

I already wrote a statement where it compares time1 to now (function to get the time), but couldn't manage to compare it to the last cell on time2.

```
SELECT SUM(d1),SUM(d2) FROM main WHERE time1 >= now;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification isn't clear, so we're just guessing what we are trying to achieve.

Here's a query that satisfies one possible interpretation of the spec:

```
SELECT SUM(m.d1)
     , SUM(m.d2)
  FROM main m
 WHERE m.time1 >= ( SELECT MAX(s.time2) 
                      FROM secondary s 
                  )
```

---

What is meant by "last cell"?  How are we to identify the row from the secondary table?

```
SELECT SUM(m.d1)
     , SUM(m.d2)
  FROM main m
 WHERE m.time1 >= ( SELECT s.time2 
                      FROM secondary s 
                     ORDER BY some_expression
                     LIMIT 1
                  )
```

Are we wanting to return just a single row, or do we want to return a row for each row in the secondary table?

```
 SELECT s.time2 
      , ( SELECT SUM(m1.d1)
            FROM main m1
           WHERE m1.time1 >= s.time2
        ) AS tot_d1
      , ( SELECT SUM(m2.d2)
            FROM main m2
           WHERE m2.time1 >= s.time2
        ) AS tot_d2
   FROM secondary s
  ORDER BY s.time2
```

Comment: If someone was to conduct an experiment on SO exploring how poor a question would have to be before it failed to elicit a sincere response from the community, do you think they might start with something like this?

Comment: Well, I honestly thought, saying "last cell" on a specific column which is time2, would be enough to state that I'm looking for the content inside the last row on table "secondary" and column "time2". I guess that wasn't quite clear. But, aside from that I honestly can't comprehend why this was a poor question.

Comment: This did the job, thanks. `SELECT SUM(d1),SUM(d2) FROM main WHERE time1 >= (SELECT time2 FROM secondary ORDER BY time2 DESC);`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(d1),SUM(d2) FROM main WHERE time1 >= (select max(time2) from table2);
```

Or is there more to it?